# Call a Java function from C code in Android using Eclipse without calling Java

Tags: java, android, c, eclipse, java-native-interface

I would like call a Java function from C code without shared library
and without a previous call of some Java function.

I know how to call my Java function, but I need get Env and JavaVM and I realy dont know how I get it. I can't use `JNI_CreateJavaVM` or `JNI_OnLoad` because I work on android. I'm using `android-ndk-r13b` to build the C code.

I'm algo using Eclipse Juno.

How could I solve this?

Comment: You cannot run Java bytecode without a Java VM.  If you cannot or do not want to launch a JVM or somehow submit a request to a JVM running outside your process, then you are out of luck.

Comment: Hey! I'd strongly recommend you try and elaborate on what is you're trying to do, since I don't think it's very clear. You kinda specified you want to do something, i.e. calling a Java function from C code, and then say that you want to do it without doing the second, i.e. without calling a Java function.

I think it would help people a lot if you try and explain it better in order to determine if it's even possible.

Comment: I need modify droidVNCserver which runs server writen in C code, because I have to call some java function from that server. There is no option write that java function in C.

Comment: It sounds like rewriting the wanted function in C may be *exactly* what you need to do.  What is the basis for your claim that that is not an option?

Comment: I will hardly rewrite the android java function. I need use some functions from media library of android.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach you could have in my opinion is using a RESTful API in your Java code, so your C code could access the function via JSON requests/responses. It would be helpful if you explain why you need the code in C. Is the C code in a separate project or is it generated by your Java code?

Answer (score 0):

From my usage of NDK, you can call the JNI_OnLoad function from android. From there you can call any class you want using a static method or through an instance object.

```
jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved)
{
    JNIEnv* env;
    if (vm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return -1;
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
```

Comment: If I use this in my C code, I get error : member reference base type 'JavaVM' (aka 'const struct JNIInvokeInterface *') is not a structure or union. If I change vm-> to (*vm)-> ,I will get error :  too few arguments to function call, expected 3, have 2. So I tried change it to if ((*vm)->GetEnv(vm,(void***)(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK)...Is it all ? No need some "extern" or something ?

Comment: I think now that problem is in android make file, because library androidvncserver is not load.

Comment: My bad the code I'm using is in a C++ file, in that case you need and extern brackets on the code. The reason you get the JavaVM error is because JNIEnv on C and C++ code is run differently. In C++ you don't need to pass the JNIEnv to the function, while in C you need to pass it, hence the reason why C ask for 3 parameters while C++ asks for 2. So the solution you added should work fine.

Comment: I had to compile shared_library and then I called function from Java to pass Env to another function in C for calling Java method. JNI doesn't work with executable C code...To Adnrian: This code will work if I load library from Activity where called function is.

Comment: This code is called when `static {System.loadLibrary("library");}` is called. Here is the full example of the JNI_OnLoad function on my jni.cpp file, 
`extern "C {
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL
JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM *vm, void *reserved) {
    JNIEnv *env;
    if ((*vm).GetEnv((void **) &env, JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        return JNI_ERR;
    }
    return JNI_VERSION_1_6;
}
}"`